# How to bind a textfield's text to a simple text label in flutter

Tags: flutter

For the most straightforward solution:

```
class _GreetingPageState extends State<GreetingPage> {
  final TextEditingController _nameController = new TextEditingController(text: 'Anonymous');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_name),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: _nameController,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This does not work as expected, while typing in TextField, Text's content doesn't get updated.

I have to change to manage another state for Text:

```
class _GreetingPageState extends State<GreetingPage> {
  String _name = '';

  final TextEditingController _nameController = new TextEditingController(text: 'Anonymous');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _nameController.addListener(
      () {
        setState(() {_name = _nameController.text;});
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_name),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              controller: _nameController,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Type your name',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This adds too much complexity for such a simple "bind a value to a text" situation.

I tried search for it, official document only give a use case where the `_nameController.text` is only used when a button is pressed, however I'd like to handle text update on user typing.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that until `setState` is not called the `Text` widget doesn't know it has to update. So you always need to call it.

You could do something like this:

```
class __GreetingPageStateState extends State<_GreetingPageState> {
  final TextEditingController _nameController =
      new TextEditingController(text: 'Anonymous');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(_nameController.text),
        TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            controller: _nameController,
            onChanged: (text) {
              setState(() {});
            }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is "empty setState" is a common technique in flutter to force an update? In my knowledge of some MVVM frameworks it is not perfectly **reactive** though.

Comment: It's not pretty for sure :D But I see no problem with this. Your new state is already in the `_nameController` you need to notify the Widget to rebuild itself. In your second example, you were doing the same just introduced an extra variable `_name`.

Comment: even this binding thru controller and setState is not working now. i'm on flutter 2.0.6.